# Open a BATCH file on Windows pc via SSH Linux client

Tags: ssh

I would like to execute a BATCH file on my Windows PC (Win10-Pro) via my Linux client.

Does this work via SSH that this BATCH file is only executed on the Windows PC?

SSHD on the Windows PC is installed and active/running.

I have unfortunately only begun to build up my SSH knowledge.
I hope you can help me with this.

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Do I understand right that you want to run `ssh ...` on your Linux system to connect to your Windows PC? Do you have an SSHD running on your Windows PC? To execute a batch file you might have to run `cmd.exe /c batch_file.cmd` instead of `batch_file.cmd`.

Comment: I assume Windows 10 or newer. Did you enable and start the OpenSSH Server? Or do you want a solution without OpenSSH? Is any of the ways presented at https://www.infosecmatter.com/accessing-windows-systems-remotely-from-linux/ viable for you?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/534514/fabian and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/534515/fabian.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. Yes the script is on my windows 10 pc (remote).

The ssh command seems to work but now I have the problem that the batch file does not do what it is supposed to do.

Maybe you can help me with this.

It should search for a file in a path and this file should then be started/run on the windows pc in the foreground.

My code in the batch file so far:

```
set match=0

for /r "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop" %%i in ("Program*") do echo %%i & set "match=%%i"

ECHO File found: %match%

ECHO Program %match% is starting.

REM Ping as workaround for timeout command.

ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL

start "Program 123" "%match%"

REM Ping as workaround for timeout command.

ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL

ECHO Finish.
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ***ask*** a new question.  If you have a question about a batch script, ask it on [SU] or [SO] — it’s off-topic on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  The fact that you have started to develop a solution is good, but please describe what happens when you run it.